# Why do I get "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' 50 record is not found' to data type int." error while calling the below function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, type-conversion

```
CREATE FUNCTION Fn_MaxSal_emp
    (@dept int)
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @maxsal int
    SET @maxsal = (SELECT MAX(sal) FROM emp WHERE deptno = @dept)
    
    IF @maxsal IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        RETURN @maxsal
    END

    RETURN (TRY_CAST(@dept AS varchar(100)) + ' record not found') 
END

SELECT dbo.fn_maxsal_emp(50) AS maxsal
```

`deptno = 50` record is not in the table, so I should get '50 record  is not found' as output but gets the error message as shown in the title

Comment: Would not you return int value @maxsal when it is not null although the contract assumes you should return varchar?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are are using another function than you have posted here. The error messages says that the varchar value " record 50 is not found" is not convertable to int. Which is correct. But the function you posted would never generate that varchar value. This function would produce "50 record not found"

Please check if you are calling the correct function, perhaps there is an old version in the database and not the version you posted here.

I tried your function here and it works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=be0ea9d1e6715d77bbc8fa4773702f01 I just changed the returns a little bit because i think it's bad practice to do not specify an explicit cast.

Comment: I know the the one u have modified in return works ,  but I need a justification for the error which I have got

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean? your function works for me so you probably are running a different version than the version you posted here

Comment: @RupeshK It may be that your actual usage is attempting to assign the return value of the function to an integer datatype - resulting in the conversion error.

Comment: @JohannesKrackowizer I want to know the reason why the function doesn’t work if we don’t use explicit cast

Comment: The error message is telling us that you tried to cast the varchar value ' 50 record is not found' to an int. Thats not possible. But the function you posted here is something different. You need to post the function that produces the error message than we can help you find the error. Or did you try to cast the result of your function to int?

Comment: The function which I have posted produces the above error msg

Comment: @RupeshK I tried [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=81787786bdf67491198cfc0d2cafb8a8) it again without a cast and i can not reproduce your error. But the error message you wrote in the title of the post does not match any string in the function you posted so there must be some difference there

Answer (score 0):

This error is created when first trying to call the function, before even reaching the `try_cast()` line, because you can't put the `**` value from the error message in the `@dept` variable used to call the method in the first place. That's where the cast from `varchar` to `int` fails.